# Prime numbers: Why is this code giving me some composite numbers?

Tags: python

I seem to be getting all the prime numbers, but some composite numbers are showing up as well. Why?

```
p=[2,]
while len(p)<35:
        next = p[-1]+1
        for i in range(len(p)):
            if next%p[i]==0:
                next+=1
                i=0
        p.append(next)
print p
```

This is the output I get:

> [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 16, 17, 19, 23, 27, 29, 31, 35, 37, 41, 43, 47, 50, 53, 59, 61, 65, 67, 71, 73, 77, 79, 83, 87, 89, 95, 97, 101, 103]

Comment: `i=0` doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because when you update `next` in the for loop, you didn't scan from beginning of the prime list to check whether the new `next` is divisible. You can try the following way.

```
p=[2,]
number=3
while len(p)<35:
    if all(number%i!=0 for i in p):
        p.append(number)
    number += 1
print p
```

Comment: I would also rename next to something else as it shadows the builtin next (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next)

Comment: @Ioan Alexandru Cucu Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you print the value of `i` in each iteration you will see the problem. The value of `i` will keep increasing.

```
Test 3 divided by 2 (p[0])
Test 4 divided by 2 (p[0])
Test 5 divided by 3 (p[1])
Test 6 divided by 2 (p[0])
Test 7 divided by 3 (p[1])
Test 7 divided by 5 (p[2])
Test 8 divided by 2 (p[0])
Test 9 divided by 3 (p[1])
Test 10 divided by 5 (p[2])
Test 11 divided by 7 (p[3])
Test 12 divided by 2 (p[0])
Test 13 divided by 3 (p[1])
Test 13 divided by 5 (p[2])
Test 13 divided by 7 (p[3])
Test 13 divided by 11 (p[4])
Test 14 divided by 2 (p[0])
Test 15 divided by 3 (p[1])
Test 16 divided by 5 (p[2])
Test 16 divided by 7 (p[3])
Test 16 divided by 11 (p[4])
Test 16 divided by 13 (p[5])
Test 17 divided by 2 (p[0])
```

Each time the code evaluate the line `for i in range(len(p))`, it doesn't consider the current value of `i`, because `range(len(p))` is actually a list (or a generator in Python 3), and so it only iterates the list, not actually doing `i = i+1` as you would have expected.

For example, consider the case when `len(p)=3`. Then `range(len(p))` would be equivalent to `[0,1,2]`. And the for loop will first take the value `0`. Then the next iteration will have the value `1`, and the third one will have the value `2`, regardless what you do to the value of `i` inside the loop body.

One solution is not to use `for i in range(len(p))`, but you do the iteration yourself:

```
next = p[-1]+1 # actually you can do next = next+1
i = 0
while i < len(p):
    if next%p[i]==0:
        next += 1
        i=0
    else:
        i+=1
p.append(next)
```